# conditional select stmnt in table query ssrs 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2005 using SQL Server.

I have 2 tables:

**Order** - contains open (unshipped) orders

**Order_History** - contains closed (shipped and invoiced) orders

I am using a `UNION ALL` to get data from both tables.  However, I would like to add 1 multivalue parameter OrderType with "open", "closed", "both" for the values so the user can say they ONLY want open, ONLY want closed, or BOTH.

Is there a way in the the dataset query (that the table uses) to put an IF or CASE so that the query runs only one select statement depending on what's chosen?

IN other words, something like:

```
"IF (@OrderType) = 'OPEN' select field a,b from Order; 
 ELSEIF (@OrderType) = 'CLOSED' then select field a,b from Order_History; 
 Else select field a,b from Order UNION ALL select field a,b from Order_History".
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to both selects in the UNION with 'open' and 'closed' respectively and then do an outer query around it to select only the values that you want with a case statement on the @orderType:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 'open' AS STATUS
  FROM order
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 'closed'
  FROM Order_History
  ) a
WHERE STATUS = CASE 
    WHEN @OrderType = 'both' THEN STATUS
    ELSE @OrderType
    END;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdc5c/3)</kbd>

Comment: hi -- thanks for the reply :) not sure if it's what I'm needing tho. If I'm understanding what you have, each time I'd be getting records from both ORDER and ORDER_HISTORY.  What I need is to JUST get records from ORDER if they select "Open", JUST from Order_History if "Closed", or do the UNION as you have it if they pick "Both".  ?  I don't understand how I would conditionally get just Order or Order_History?  thanks!

Comment: @KimJones. This does exactly that. the CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause will filter the results based on the `@ordertype`. If they select open, it will filter only the results from order. If he picks closed, you get the results from order_history. if he picks 'both', the where doesn't filter nothing. In a single query, you can't just select from one table or another.

Comment: Thanks!  However, I'm getting an error when I use the query in my dataset(just doing a simple select to test):  'SELECT     *
FROM         (SELECT     *, 'Open' AS STATUS
                       FROM          [ORDER]
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT     *, 'Closed' AS STATUS
                       FROM         ORDER_HISTORY) AS a
WHERE     (STATUS = CASE WHEN (at)OrderType = 'Both' THEN STATUS ELSE (at)OrderType END;)'    with the "end;" in there, I get an error incorrect status near ';' and if removed, error near ')'   ? had to replace @ with (at) to post this

Comment: remove those () around the WHERE clause. The rest i can't tell  what is wrong, since this query works on the fiddle. And make sure `@ordertype` is defined. About the END; , it is part of the CASE, you can't remove it.

Comment: ok, did that (and I have @OrderType as a parameter) but now it's saying "an expresion of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','".  Here's my statement:         SELECT ORDER_NUM, CUST_NUM
FROM  (SELECT     ORDER_NUM, CUST_NUM, 'Open' AS STATUS
FROM [ORDER]
 UNION ALL
SELECT     ORDER_NUM, CUST_NUM, 'Closed' AS STATUS
FROM ORDER_HISTORY) AS a
WHERE     STATUS = CASE WHEN (at)OrderType = 'Both' THEN STATUS ELSE (at)OrderType END;        and again, REALLY appreciate your help! :)  and again,I have to use (at) instead of @ to post this...

Comment: never mind!  It's working :)  I had defaulted in the 3 options in the parameter and that caused the error :)  THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR HELP!!!!  :)  Kim